# T-SQL expand "table_name" to "db.dbo.table_name" in a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to pass in a reference to a table name and join it with a known database and schema reference? For instance, I am attempting to write a t-sql function to return a value based on three parameters, a column name in the target table, an id field and a table name with out the `db.dbo` reference for convenience. I would hope to be able to write `dbo.getvalueforid('NAME', 'NAME_ID', 'NAME_TABLE')` and have a reference to `DB.DBO` in the function such that `SELECT NAME FROM [DB].[DBO].NAME_TABLE WHERE NAME_ID = NAME_TABLE.ID` is generated.

For reference here is the function I am working on:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getvalueforid', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION getvalueforid;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getvalueforid(@colname varchar(20), @idfield varchar(20), @targettable varchar(20))
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS 
-- Returns the name from nameid.
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value varchar(255);
    SELECT  @value = @colname
    FROM '[DB].[DBO].' + @targettable n 
    WHERE @idfield = n.u2_id; 
    RETURN @value;
END;
GO
```

Comment: No you can't do that in a function. In order to do what you are doing would require dynamic sql which can't be done in a function. Why are you trying to create "the one function to rule them all"? This is like trying to create a method in .net that does everything.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the comment. It was simply for convenience but I can certainly see that it could be a little silly. In fact, this comes to mind: [XKCD: The General Problem](http://xkcd.com/974/.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to write what Sean Lange has already explained in your comments section, Hence the following Stored Procedure.

Also I have used TOP 1 clause in select statement just in case if there are duplicates so the procedure wont error out.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getvalueforid
  @colname     SYSNAME
, @idfield     SYSNAME
, @targettable SYSNAME
, @Value       varchar(255) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' SELECT TOP 1 @Value  = ' + QUOTENAME(@colname)
         + N' FROM [DB].[DBO].'+ QUOTENAME(@targettable)
         + N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@idfield) + N' = u2_id'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@Value varchar(255) OUTPUT'
                     ,@Value OUTPUT
END
GO
```